# Why in list of table privileges I can not see my table privileges?

Tags: sql

I created the table and granted the select statement to the role. Then I grant the role to user. User can perform select statement on my table, but he can not see information about this privilege via SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;
Step-by-step below by HR user:

```
CREATE TABLE A1 (ID NUMBER);
Table A1 created.

CREATE TABLE A2 (ID NUMBER);
Table A2 created.

CREATE ROLE ROLE1;
Role ROLE1 created.

GRANT SELECT ON A1 TO ROLE1;
Grant succeeded.

GRANT SELECT ON A2 TO ROLE1;
Grant succeeded.

GRANT ROLE1 TO MAX;
Grant succeeded.
```

Then steps by user MAX:

```
SET ROLE ROLE1;
Role ROLE1 succeeded.

SELECT * FROM HR.A1;--successfull

SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;--successful, but no rows
```

Whre is the problem? Whi can clarify?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please describe which database and database version you use.
Table user_tab_privs is a table from oracle dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

User MAX has no table privileges, only privileges on role ROLE1.
Use the `USER_ROLE_PRIVS` to show these privileges.
`user_tab_privs` is limited to the privileges of the connected/current user.
Table *user_tab_privs* is a table from **Oracle** dictionary. So i suggest a Oracle database.
After the `grant select` you will get an entry from `user_tab_privs` **if you are connected as the user HR**. If you use a *dba user* you have to query `dba_tab_privs`.